# insert mongodb using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I have a problem insert mongodb using vb.net.

```
Public Sub runMongoDBQuery(ByVal nameDatabase As String, ByVal nameCollection As String, ByVal queryBson As BsonDocument, ByVal serverString As String)


        Dim mongo1 As MongoServer = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost/?safe=true") 
        mongo1.Connect()
        Dim db = mongo1.GetDatabase(nameDatabase)
        Dim collection1 = db(nameCollection) 
        collection1.Save(queryBson)// this is hang
        mongo1.Disconnect()


 End Sub
```

When I user this function, it run smoothly  and suddenly hang.

It doesn't throw exception but hang.

The problems run very rarely.

All the function did is saving queryBson

I will:

- Check content of queryBson
- Check log of mongodb server
- Update the question once I got more info

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in the shell?

Comment: No. In fact, the problem happens only VERY rarely. one out of 9700 run or something.

Comment: Are you sure it hangs, or does it just take a really, really, long time? Does the whole DB hang, or just that client? Do you have the logs set to "verbose=true" and are there any clues in there?

Comment: I haven't checked the log. The mongo db server is not hang. It still serve many other projects.

Comment: Never mind. Restarting mongodb solves the problem perfectly. Not sure why. The log is too high, 3GB. I guess the next question would be how to limit log in mongodb.

Comment: Is this a 32-bit mongo install perhaps? they'll have trouble working with bigger files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by restarting mongodb and deleting the log. Thanks to Cirrus's comment.

The log is 3GB and I strongly suspected it's the culprit.

Such a high log is useless because text editor can't open it anyway. Deleting the log without restarting mongodb causes a side effect where logs are no longer created.

I will soon ask another question how to limit log for mongodb, maybe on the database forum.

This question has a sequel:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25658/how-to-keep-mongodb-log-small